# why does there exists two $HOME/.gem and $HOME/.rvm/gem folders

Tags: ruby-on-rails

rvm is used for installing ruby. Inspite of that there exists two .gem folders $HOME/.gem and $HOME/.rvm/gem. Looks like **bundle install** uses the $HOME/.rvm/gem folder. Then what is the need for the $HOME/.gem folders?.

Answer (score 0):

`$HOME/.gem` is where your user's system ruby is, and `$HOME/.rvm/gem` stores rvm's ones. You can check it by yourself:

```
bash-4.2$ ruby -r rubygems -e "p Gem.path"
["/home/zrl3dx/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353", "/home/zrl3dx/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353@global"]
bash-4.2$ rvm use system
Now using system ruby.
bash-4.2$ ruby -r rubygems -e "p Gem.path"
["/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1", "/home/zrl3dx/.gem/ruby/1.9.1"]
```

Comment: I have not installed any ruby apart from using the rvm. I am using ubuntu-12.04 and after using the command 'rvm use system' and then typed the ruby --version and the output is The program 'ruby' can be found in the following packages: . But i donot understand who might have created the $HOME/.gem folder. Its size is about 7.8M
 * ruby1.8
 * ruby1.9.1
Try: sudo apt-get install <selected package>

Comment: Strange, I'm using on one machine ubuntu 12.04 too and I've had ruby  installed by default. If you can, run `rvm implode`, this will remove all traces of rvm from your system and check what have left. I'm convinced rvm stays in `.rvm` directory.